# ASRock H55M-GE: How far can I upgrade my RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, memory-limit

I have a ASRock H55M-GE that supports DDR3 1600/1333/1066 and I'd like to upgrade to 16GB.

I was looking at the [manual](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/H55M-GE.pdf) that states *"Max. capacity of system memory: 16GB"* (p. 6) but I can't tell if that's the capacity *per slot* or the total sum.

Does anyone know? Is it safe to buy 2x8GB or should I stick (no pun intended) to 4x4GB?

Thank you

Comment: "Max. capacity" is what it says - total, not per slot - unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was looking at the manual that states "Max. capacity of system
> memory: 16GB" (p. 6) but I can't tell if that's the capacity per slot
> or the total sum.

The specification page indicates the maximum amount of system memory that the motherboard can support is 16 GB.

> [image]
>
> - Max. capacity of system memory: 16GB

[Source](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H55M-GE/index.asp)

> Is it safe to buy 2x8GB or should I stick (no pun intended) to 4x4GB?

ASRock only qualified DDR3 modules with 4 GB capacity and smaller.  It is very unlikely your system would even POST with any module greater than 4 GB due to the chipset used.

[ASRock H55M-GE QVL](https://www.asrock.com/mb/memory/H55M-GE.pdf)

Comment: Ah, Memory QVL. Thanks! I didn't know the specific term to search for

Comment: Qualified Vendor List.  Means that the manufacturer actually tested with those modules and confirmed they work.  It's possible that it will work with other modules, but given that they only tested up to 4 GB sticks, there's probably a fundamental limitation with the motherboard on max size.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage - Exactly.  I only have the motherboard and chipset specifications to determine if the system supports modules greater then 4 GB